# Check if a list has exclusively duplicate elements (i.e., no unique elements)

Tags: python, list

I have an array with an even number of `int`s and want to check if all of those elements are 'paired', ie `[0, 1, 0, 1]` has a pair of `1`s and a pair of `0`s vs `[0, 1, 1, 2]` has only one `0` and one `2`.

My first thought was to cast it to a set and check if the set had a length of half of the original:

```
def isPaired(arr):
    return len(arr) / 2 == len(set(arr)
```

But that's incorrect if the arr is `[0, 1, 0, 0]`.

my next thought was to sort the array, and compare each even-numbered index with the next index:

```
def isPaired(arr):
    arr.sort
    for i in range(0, len(arr) - 1):
        if i % 2 == 0 && arr[i] != arr[i+1]:
            return False
    return True
```

This works, but the runtime is at least the runtime of the sort. Is there a solution to this problem without sorting the array?

Comment: You can create a dictionary and keep the number as key and the value as the count. At the end, you need to make sure that all values are even (to form pairs)

Comment: @newbie that's `Counter` from the `collections` package

Comment: Cool. This actually is very useful in many places

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Counter` like this:

```
from collections import Counter
all(c % 2 == 0 for c in Counter([0, 1, 0, 1]).values())
# True
```

You can also sort and then compare consecutive elements:

```
l = sorted([0, 1, 0, 1])
all(x == y for x, y in zip(l[::2], l[1::2]))
# True
```

Complexity wise, prefer the first option since its worst case complexity is only linear.

Comment: with the counter, you then only need to check the total number of elements (half of the size of the array), and the count for the most common (2)

Comment: @njzk2 Not necessarily, since `[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2]` could also be a valid input. Unless I misunderstood what you meant to say.

Comment: that's something the OP hasn't specified, although it's a valid question: do 4 items count as 2 pairs, or is does it count as no pair at all. But given the current implementation posted by the OP, I think you are right

Answer (score 1):

This uses less memory:

```
INPUT = [0, 1, 0 , 1]

odd = set()
for n in INPUT:
    if n in odd: 
        odd.remove(n)
    else:
        odd.add(n)

print(not odd)
```

It accepts `[1,1,1,1]` as two pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
def have_pairs(a):
    temp_dict = dict()
    for i in a:
        if i in temp_dict:
            temp_dict[i] += 1
        else:
            temp_dict[i] = 1
    frequency = temp_dict.values()
    pairs = True
    for i in frequency:
        if i % 2 == 1:
            pairs = False
            break
    return pairs


a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]
print(have_pairs(a))
# True

a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
print(have_pairs(a))
# False
```